# Cannot open host WCF REST Services

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, rest

I am trying to implement some WCF and REST services to upload a file on my server, and I have found some code which I am trying to implement, but no success yet.

#### My code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string address = "http://localhost/UploadService/UploadService.svc/UploadFile/theFile.txt";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(address);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        string fileContents = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
        byte[] bodyContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents);
        reqStream.Write(bodyContents, 0, bodyContents.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription); 

    }

}

public class UploadService : IUploadService
{

    #region IUploadService Members

    public void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContent)
    {
        using (StreamReader fileContentReader = new StreamReader(fileContent))
        {
            string content = fileContentReader.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(@"c:\temp", fileName), content);
        }
    }  

    #endregion
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IUploadService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}")]
    void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContent);  
}
```

#### Web.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="UploadService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IUploadService" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="RestBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

At the moment, in the response `resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();` I am getting:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try `netstat -ano` at a command prompt to see what the other application is: look for `TCP 127.0.0.1:1157` then look up the process ID (right-hand column) in task manager (ctrl-shift-escape; you may need to view columns, add process ID)

Comment: its listed as listening.  I think its not an issue with the port but with the code itself, since I changed the url but still same error

Comment: OK, but it shouldn't be listed at all: if your code isn't running at the time then someone else is listening on that port and that's blocking you. Unless I've misunderstood? But I can well believe it's some other WCF issue.

Comment: ok i stopped the application and there is no listing now, but I still get the same message :(

Comment: when i stopped the localhost, i got the following error The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. in the response

Comment: Is there any namespace in your application? Is your contract or service placed in any namespace?

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF service? It looks like you're using IIS, but you didn't mention an .svc file and it sounds like you've made some changes since when you first posted. Are you able to browse directly to http://localhost/UploadService/UploadService.svc in a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a service request from the same process that is hosting the service. I think they should be separate, e.g. your service host in a console app and your test in another.

Comment: Hi Fabio I had already tried that but i still got the same problems, that is why i put everything together.

Comment: Have you got anything at all in your config, e.g. a metadata endpoint?

Comment: Hey Fabio I changed a bit my code, and I am getting a different error now.  Basically I added the service to the localhost, by creating a new one, and then calling it from the windows app.  You can see my updated code in the beginning of the thread

Comment: Try to change includeExceptionDetailInFaults to true and view the service with IE, do you get any more details?

Comment: Johann, please could you start another question - this one is not relevant any more... Don't mean to be pedantic, but also your code is not showing up properly in my Chrome... Cheers.

Comment: Hi guys I solved it.  I did BasicHTTPBinding and it worked.  Thanks for all your help!  Very much appreciated