# WCF REST with WPF for upload

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, rest

I want to use WCF REST for uploading files from my WPF application. Any example code how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an exact duplicate but it contains code related to what you want to do: [Cannot open host WCF REST Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714751/cannot-open-host-wcf-rest-services)